# Rich Faces's 4.0 Autocomplete component don't fit size

Tags: autocomplete, richfaces, jquery-autocomplete

I have a autocomplete component, but it doesn't fit like I want.

I want the pop up width fitting the input field, same size... I tried a lot of attributes but without success.

**Is this, maybe, a limitation?**

[image]

See that, pop up is smaller than the origin input field. What do I need to do?

```
.inputPesquisa {
width: 77%;
}
```

...

```
<div class="pesquisa">
        <rich:autocomplete value="#{pesquisarBean.pesquisa}" styleClass="inputPesquisa"
            autocompleteList="#{bean.todos}" minChars="4" mode="client" layout="div">
            <div>ata</div>
        </rich:autocomplete>
        <a4j:commandButton value="Pesquisar" render="out, scroller"
            styleClass="botaoPesquisa" execute="@form"
            actionListener="#{pesquisarBean.processAction}" />
            <rich:messages showDetail="false" ></rich:messages>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into your question, tho it's a little old.

Create the following CSS style if you want to change your text box input properties:

```
.inputPesquisa .rf-au-inp {
    width: 350px;
}
```

I tried creating the style with all the style tree and this works (for all autocomplete components):

```
.rf-au-lst-cord .rf-au-shdw .rf-au-lst-dcrtn .rf-au-lst-scrl {
    max-height: 300px; /* Bigger than this shows scroller */
    width: 100%; /* This is enough to make all the autocomplete lists look nice */
}
```

But when I try to add the component's class

```
.inputPesquisa .rf-au-lst-cord .rf-au-shdw .rf-au-lst-dcrtn .rf-au-lst-scrl {
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It doesn't work anymore. Maybe it's the case of opening a Jira. So, just cut to the chase and include this in your CSS:

```
.rf-au-lst-dcrtn .rf-au-lst-scrl {
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes, a old question... I already solve that, But your answer seems to have the right approach. Rich Faces documentation has information about what css you need to customize. But you forget to put the !important parameter to override the CSS default.